# Is there an alternative to writing SQL query statement to display separate column value in same row?

Tags: sql-server, group-by, subquery, common-table-expression

I am deriving a SQL query statement to prepare a statistical report. In 
my report, I need to display values under few separate columns. These 
`column` have different numeric ranges. `(I.e.1, 2-4, 5-10, 11-19, 20-49, 
TotalForEachCategory)`. How do I formulate my `SQL` query to do the same? 
Currently these values come in separate rows.

I am working on preparing SSRS report. For this, I need to develop SQL 
statements. columns reflecting in report are not physical in SQL table. 
Hence, I need to derive them doing SQL aggregations. For one instance, I 
need to display "Total number of vehicle fleet carriers" for each category 
falling under different fleet ranges.

Currently my results occur like below. (incorrect)

```
                            Fleet Ranges
----------------------------------------------------------------------
|  1  |  2-4  |  5-10  | 11-19  |  20-49  | TotalForCategory
----------------------------------------------------------------------
| 70  |   0   |   0    |   0    |    0    |        70
| 0   |  38   |   0    |   0    |    0    |        38
| 0   |   1   |   0    |   0    |    0    |         1
| 0   |   0   |  27    |   0    |    0    |        27
```

[image: Current incorrect result]

What I have tried so far

SQL query:

```
SELECT
    (CASE WHEN F.mot_averagefleetsize = 1 THEN COUNT(M.mot_carriernumbername) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Fleet_Range_1',
    (CASE WHEN F.mot_averagefleetsize BETWEEN 2 AND 4 THEN COUNT(M.mot_carriernumbername) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Fleet_Range_2-4',
    (CASE WHEN F.mot_averagefleetsize BETWEEN 5 AND 10 THEN COUNT(M.mot_carriernumbername) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Fleet_Range_5-10',
    (CASE WHEN F.mot_averagefleetsize BETWEEN 11 AND 19 THEN COUNT(M.mot_carriernumbername) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Fleet_Range_11-19',
    (CASE WHEN F.mot_averagefleetsize BETWEEN 20 AND 49 THEN COUNT(M.mot_carriernumbername) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Fleet_Range_20-49'
FROM
    Table1 F
INNER JOIN 
    Table2 M ON M.column1 = F.column2
GROUP BY
    F.mot_averagefleetsize
```

My expected result should be like below:

```
                                  Fleet Ranges
----------------------------------------------------------------------
           |  1  |  2-4  |  5-10  | 11-19  |  20-49  | TotalForCategory
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Category #1| 70  |  39   |  27    |   0    |    0    |       136
           |
```

Comment: almost there.. `sum` is what you are looking for

Comment: @maSTAShuFu: how do I derive total of those summed column?

Comment: check answer.below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using `SUM` after Derived Table Aggregation. you will need to specify the categoryfield

```
select 
categoryfield,
sum (Fleet_Range_1) Fleet_Range_1
sum (Fleet_Range_2-4) Fleet_Range_2-4
sum (Fleet_Range_5-10) Fleet_Range_5-10
sum (Fleet_Range_11-1) Fleet_Range_11-1
sum (Fleet_Range_20-49) Fleet_Range_20-49
from (
select
categoryfield
,(CASE WHEN F.mot_averagefleetsize = 1 THEN COUNT(M.mot_carriernumbername) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Fleet_Range_1'
,(CASE WHEN F.mot_averagefleetsize BETWEEN 2 AND 4 THEN COUNT(M.mot_carriernumbername) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Fleet_Range_2-4'
,(CASE WHEN F.mot_averagefleetsize BETWEEN 5 AND 10 THEN COUNT(M.mot_carriernumbername) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Fleet_Range_5-10'
,(CASE WHEN F.mot_averagefleetsize BETWEEN 11 AND 19 THEN COUNT(M.mot_carriernumbername) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Fleet_Range_11-19'
,(CASE WHEN F.mot_averagefleetsize BETWEEN 20 AND 49 THEN COUNT(M.mot_carriernumbername) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Fleet_Range_20-49'
from Table1 F
inner join Table2 M on M.column1 = F.column2
group by F.mot_averagefleetsize, categoryfield
) x
group by categoryfield
```

Comment: Thank you for providing insight. That was very close what I was looking for.